# pandas SettingWithCopyWarning when using a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand pandas SettingWithCopyWarning, what exactly triggers it an how to avoid it. I want to take a selection of columns from a data frame and then work with this selection of columns. I need to fill missing values and replace all values larger than 1 with 1.

I understand that sub_df=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] produces a copy and that seems to be what I want. Could someone explain why the copy warning is triggered here, whether it's problem, and how I should avoid it?

I read a lot about chained assignment in this context, am I doing this here?

```
data={'col1' : [25 , 0, 100, None],
    'col2' : [50 , 0 , 0, None],
      'col3' : [None, None, None, 100],
      'col4' : [ 20 , 20 , 20 , 20 ],
      'col5' : [1,1,2,3]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
sub_df=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
sub_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
sub_df[df>1]=1 # produces the copy warning
sub_df
```

What really confuses me is why this warning is not triggered if I am not using a new name for my subset of columns as below:

```
data={'col1' : [25 , 0, 100, None],
    'col2' : [50 , 0 , 0, None],
      'col3' : [None, None, None, 100],
      'col4' : [ 20 , 20 , 20 , 20 ],
      'col5' : [1,1,2,3]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df[df>1]=1 # does not produce the copy warning
df
```

Thanks!

Comment: The 2 code snippets are semantically different, in the first one it's ambiguous whether you want to operate on a copy or a view of the orig df, on the second one you overwrite the original df with a subset of the original df

Comment: thanks, so is the solution to make it clear to pandas that I do want to create a copy? how exactly would I do that?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, if your intention is to operate on a copy then do `sub_df=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].copy()` if your intention is to operate on a view, you'd better off defining a list of the cols and using the new [`indexers`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) so `df[col_list'].fillna(0)` and then `df.loc[df > 1, col_list] = 1`

Comment: thanks! that's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 code snippets are semantically different, in the first it's ambiguous whether you want to operate on a view or a copy of the original df, in the second you overwrite `df` with a subset of the `df` so there is no ambiguity.

If you want to operate on a copy then do this:

```
sub_df=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].copy()
```

if you want to operate on a view then I suggest using a list of cols and referencing them using the new [indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) like the following:

```
df[col_list].fillna(0)
```

and then

```
df.loc[df > 1, col_list] = 1
```

Comment: Will that first line not do two copies?

Comment: @Konstantin sorry I don't understand, the first line creates a second df which is a sub-section of the orig df but it will be a distinct copy, not a view

Comment: I was just wondering if df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] not already creates a copy, so that adding a .copy() to it would produce a second copy.

Comment: @Konstantin it depends, it may return a copy or a view, a warning will be raised if you try to modify this, this is where the confusion arises so you need to be explicit in your intentions